# Expanding a condensed list to find the median

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, median

Column A has a x number of units and column b has an xx amount set for those number of units (a1 = 3, b1 = 100, a2 = 2, b2 = 150, etc).  Is there a way to easily write out all items in column b the number of times specified in column a to easily use the median function?  In this example: 100, 100, 100, 150, 150 = 100 median amount.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(FREQUENCY((SUM(B1:B4)+{0,1})/2,SUMIF(A1:A4,"<="&A1:A4,B1:B4)),A1:A4))
```

For example the following returns Median = `2.5`

```
Num   Amount
3     200
2     150
4     100
1     150
```

The ranges can be extended to fit the required data range. The Amount column is a positive integer and Num is any numerical value.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I actually wanted the median number amount ($150 with your data).  Hard to describe but you got it! I just had to change the A's to B's and vice versa and it totally worked!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes it should work ok with the ranges either way around. Glad this worked for you.